# PayPal - IPN History Page - User/view permission setting

Tags: paypal, permissions, paypal-ipn, history

Help! Another admin/user needs to have access/view the IPN History Page. When he clicks the "IPN History page" link, this message is returned: Feature Not Available - Sorry this feature is currently unavailable....

The PayPal business account owner doesn't want to give full access to other administrative users. All of us have researched/key word searched, messaged the message center, but can't find the answer.

Which permission needs to be given to the user profile, so the PayPal administrative user can view the IPN history?

Thanks so much for any help! It's probably just me, but PayPal support/resources have me about ready to jump through a window. ;)

Pete

Comment: Make sure View Profile is one of the included permissions

Comment: hello I find myself in the same situation could you find an answer to this?